# mosquitto_pub fails first try but then succeeds

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, mosquitto, aws-iot

I'm using the mosquitto library.  Specifically, I'm running the following command...

```
mosquitto_pub --cafile rootCA.pem --cert deviceCertAndCACert.crt --key deviceCert.key -h <account>.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com -p 8883 -q 1 -t foo/bar -I anyclientID --tls-version tlsv1.2 -m 'Hello' -d
```

The first or second time I run the command, it always fails.  After that, it runs successfully.  I'm trying to put this in an automated script so I'd like it to run successfully the first time.  Are there any flags that I can add to the command to ensure that it runs successfully the first time?

This is the error I get...

```
Client anyclientID6181 sending CONNECT
Error: The connection was lost.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does it fail? [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64159535/edit) to show the failure mode (you might want to enable debug mode in `mosquitto_pub` with `-d`)

Comment: Hi @hardillb ... thanks for the reply.  Yes, I have the -d flag added to the command.  I edited my post to include the error.

Comment: Do you have another client, say a Subscriber, that is using the same `-I anyclientID` value??  That would account for the dropped connections.

Comment: @JDAllen - nope, no subscriber client.  I'm following this tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/setting-up-just-in-time-provisioning-with-aws-iot-core/. Everything works great except for the unreliable mosquitto_pub command.